# Datasource is not autowired whith java based spring configuration

Tags: spring, jdbc, annotations

I am trying to configure a database access in spring with javabased configuration following guidelines given in [this good article about profiles configuration](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).
For some reason I do not get, the injection process fails when I execute the following test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig.class })
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class MySQLDBTests {

    @Autowired
    DynUserInDbDao dbAccess;

    @Test
    public void testouverture() {
        assertNotNull(dbAccess);
    }

}
```

The Main config class is as follows

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dynamease")
public class MainConfig {

    @Autowired
    DatabaseConfig dbConfig;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate userDBJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dbConfig.userDBDatasource());
    }

}
```

And the database config comes from the following classes :

```
public interface DatabaseConfig {
 public DataSource userDBDatasource();
}

@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class MySQLDBConfig implements DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource userDBDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource toReturn = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dyn_core",
                "user", "pwd");
        toReturn.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return toReturn;
    }
 }
```

mysql is running with good configuration of database and user/pwd as well as privileges and grants.

Thanks in advance for your help, below is the copy of the trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynUserDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.dynamease.repository.impl.DynUserDaoImpl.userDBJdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBJdbcTemplate' defined in class com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig.userDBJdbcTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBDatasource' defined in class path resource [com/dynamease/core/config/MySQLDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.dynamease.repository.impl.DynUserDaoImpl.userDBJdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBJdbcTemplate' defined in class com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig.userDBJdbcTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBDatasource' defined in class path resource [com/dynamease/core/config/MySQLDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBJdbcTemplate' defined in class com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig.userDBJdbcTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBDatasource' defined in class path resource [com/dynamease/core/config/MySQLDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig.userDBJdbcTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBDatasource' defined in class path resource [com/dynamease/core/config/MySQLDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDBDatasource' defined in class path resource [com/dynamease/core/config/MySQLDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:298)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2b5bfdef.userDBDatasource(<generated>)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig.userDBJdbcTemplate(MainConfig.java:59)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9d248192.CGLIB$userDBJdbcTemplate$1(<generated>)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9d248192$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c9ee7885.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9d248192.userDBJdbcTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:150)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig.userDBDatasource(MySQLDBConfig.java:22)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2b5bfdef.CGLIB$userDBDatasource$0(<generated>)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2b5bfdef$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a26cf185.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at com.dynamease.core.config.MySQLDBConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2b5bfdef.userDBDatasource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:147)
    ... 89 more
```

Comment: Take a look at your stacktrace. `Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]` is quite a give away. You don't have the MySQL JDBC Drivers on your classpath.

Comment: Right, basic mistake, thanks for figuring that out. Yves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per M.Deinum comment, the mistake here is that the mysql jdbc driver is not on the class path.
In copy/pasting the code from another project, I forgot to update the maven pom.xml with the required mysql dependencies.

It works now.